# How to combine two different chart by using VBA coding in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Set rng = Sheets("Before").Range("B1:B11")
Set rng2 = Sheets("After").Range("B1:B11")

'create chart
Set cht = Sheets("Plot").Shapes.AddChart2

'Give chart some data
cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng
cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng2
```

when I using this two code:

```
cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng
cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng2
```

the first chart is draw but it is replace by the second chart. How to combine two chart into one diagram?

I already try declare one variable to add the two chart. But it is unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

For something like this, I would select different ranges, and plot each in one single chart. See the link below for details.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/select-data-for-a-chart-5fca57b7-8c52-4e09-979a-631085113862

When that is done, turn on the Macro Recorder and click through all the steps you need. Then the Recorder will generate all the code you want/need. You will inevitable get some superfluous code, but you will also have the exact code that you need to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the second data source as a new series. `SetSourceData` takes over the entire chart source data range.

```
Set rng = Sheets("Before").Range("B1:B11")
Set rng2 = Sheets("After").Range("B1:B11")

'create chart
Set cht = Sheets("Plot").Shapes.AddChart2

'Give chart some data
cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng

' Add Data
With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .Values = rng2
End With
```

It may be more complicated if cell B1 in each sheet is used for the series names.